# Control refactor snippets

Tags: flutter, ide

I use flutter and Visual Studio Code.
How to customize this menu?
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I think the refactor window is auto generated based on the selection

Comment: I believe that those come from the analyzer, and are not very easy to edit for mere mortals.